# Android Studio and debug inapp purchase

Tags: android

I have a general question about android and debug in-app purchase.

I have developed my application and I am stuck to test the purchase of my product.

If I launch the application on my phone from Android Studio I have an error, something like there is no product. I think my application is not identified/accepted by the Play store.

If I create a release and install the application from the play store I can purchase the product but I do not know if it's working. My application react like if it's ok but I can't check it. I use a test account consequently I do not pay and I do not see the purchase in my account. Is there somewhere we should see the tests purchases ?

Finally, now if I try to launch the application on the phone from Android Studio, Android Studio tell me the sign key is different and I need to uninstall the application first.

I think my problem is there, I should be able to have the same sign keys this way I can test/use the play store from android studio directly ( and have the debug mode ...).

I have configured the build process with the same configuration that in "Build -> Generated signed bundle" but it's not working.
Is there something like Google sign the app with a specific key to authorized it to access to the play store ?

How should we debug the process of purchase in the play store ?

Comment: You cannot debug the purchase sequence. The only way to do it is upload the build on playstore. Use an internal test build from playstore. Add a test account to playstore. If the response is successful than it will work for everyone

Comment: Thank, you have right. I have done it by creating an internal team and release.